# Is there any drawback in implementing it as a normal web service instead of using data web service and entity Framework to expose OData?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need to expose few OData end-points, for which there is no direct table to connect in my DB to get data and use data web service or Entity Framework.So I am developing it as a normal web service and returning List of custom objects.

Custom objects have DataContract attribute in the definition.

My question is, Is there any drawback with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

YOu mean except odata clients not able to access your things (big no no) and you lacking ny ensible query semantics?

No, not really. It is a less functional and lacking standard solution ,but if that is ok with you.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Nope. But you may want to searc for "semantic web service". And read abot the features OData provides. And read th excel documentation - excel can natively deal with Odata.